# Conjugacy Class in a matrix group with columns of standard basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, lie-groups

I want to find the conjugacy classes of this group:
$$G=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3):a_i=\pm e_j\}\subset GL_3(\mathbb C)$$
I know that $S_3$ is one of the subgroups of this group, so I can check which elements of $S_3$ continues to be conjugate in our group,

I know that in $Z(G)$ there is two elements $I,-I$.

I know that I have to check the diagonal matrices on which ones are conjugate, but I don't know how to finish and find the others conjugacy class of this group, and I don't Know how to find the number of the elements of the conjugacy class.
I'll be thankful for help

Comment: Here are a few hints and comments - I can add more detail later if necessary. We have $|G|=48$. Since $-I \in Z(G)$  with $\det(-I)=-1$, if $C$ is a conjugacy class of elements with determinant $1$, then $\{-x: x \in C\}$ is a class of elements with determinant $-1$, so this reduces the problem to the $24$ elements with determinant $1$. Two obvious classes are $\{I\}$ and a class of order $3$ containing diagonal matrices. A matrix of order $3$ has centralizer of order $6$, so its class has $8$ elements....

Comment: ... Apart from that there are two classes with six elements, one with elements of order $2$  order two containing $-x$ with $x$ a permutation matrix, and the other elements of order $4$ containing $[[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]$.

Comment: can you please explain how you know that there is 24 elements in Z (G) @DerekHolt

Comment: I didn't say that, as you said yourself there are just two elements in $Z(G)$, $I$ and $-I$. I said that there were $24$ elements that have determinant one, which follows from the fact that the matrices with dete4rminant one form a subgroup if index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: I thought that I was wrong, thank you ! @DerekHolt

Comment: Can you please explain to me why in the (second comment) there is classes with six elements, why specific six, how can I know how much it have?, I'll be thankful for help @DerekHolt

Comment: Probably the easiest way to see that is to calculate their centralizers, which have order 8. Let me denote the three unit vectors by $I,J,K$. Then, for example, the matrix with rows $(J,I,K)$ (which has order $2$) is centralized by the eight elements $\pm(I,J,K)$, $\pm(I,J,-K)$, $(\pm(J,I,K)$, $\pm(J,I,-K)$.

Comment: Thanks know I understood why its 6, but can you please explain how u know that the elements in the centralized (to matrix with order 2) its look like that ±(I,J,K), ±(I,J,−K), (±(J,I,K), ±(J,I,−K) ? What did you use? in the matrix with order 3 the centralized have 6 elements how can I know how it looks ? @DerekHolt

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot answer an endless stream of questions about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This group is a wreath product of a cyclic group of order $2$ (i.e. $\pm 1$) with a symmetric group of order $3$. Thus $S_3$ is also a factor group and one can use the classes of $S_3$ as first approximation (i.e. classes of $G$ that will map into the class of $S_3$), which also gives how coordinates are permuted.

- The class of the identity in $S_3$ gives matrices that are diagonal with 0,1,2,3 entries that are $-1$, thus
  4 classes, including the two in the centre and two of size 3 outside the centre.
- Next come matrices that map to elements of order $2$. Their shape must be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&*&0\\*&0&0\\0&0&*\\
  \end{array}\right)$ (or conjugate). You get 4 classes distingiuished by determinant $\pm1$ and element order 2 or 4. All have 6 elements.
- Finally, you get two classes that map to elements of order $3$. Their shape must be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&*&0\\0&0&*\\*&0&0\\
  \end{array}\right)$ (or conjugate). One has elements of order 3 and determinant 1, the other order $6$ and determinant $-1$. Both have 8 elements.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be thankful if you can explain more  the first point- Is this all possible matrix that are diagonal in the group, and can you please explain how you know the number of the classes - in the the first point how you know that there is 4 classes, in the point 2 how u know that there is 4 and the last one 2? can you please tell me What u used  to know the number of classes @ahulpke

Comment: Yes, the first are all possible diagonal matrices. As for completeness, clearly matrices as described must exist in the group, and an easy combinatorial count establishes the sizes given as lower bounds. As this exhausts the 48 elements of the group, it must be the exact class sizes, and there cannot be other classes.

Comment: thanks, I understood that u got all classes, but please can u explain in point 2 why specific 4 classes how can I know that? @ahulpke

Comment: As for the second point, it is easy to find elements of this shape of orders 2 and 4, and of determinant 1 and -1. That gives you (btw. note the spelling of this word) 4 combinations, and thus at least 4 conjugacy classes.

Comment: can I ask two last questions? I'll be thankful for help, in point 2 why there is 6 elements and not 8 can you please explain why 6?, and in point 3 why to elements with order 3 the determinant is 1 and to elements with order 6 the determinant is -1 And not the other way around ?.  This is what is left for me to understand the whole solution I would be happy if you answer me @ahulpke

Comment: In part 2 there need to be at least 6. And it can't be more since that would exceed the group order. As for the orders 3/6, write down a matrix and check the order.

Comment: thank you very much! @ahulpke